# Function added to hook "new_to_publish" not executing - custom plugin

Tags: plugins, posts, hooks, email, publish

I was creating a custom plugin which was to send certain emails based on the content/category of a post, but whilst trying to do that, I ran into some problems just getting a basic email sent out. Am I hooking on to the wrong function here? When I publish a post, nothing happens.

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Conditional Emailing
* Description: Sends emails based on categories.
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Ceds
*/

add_action( 'new_to_publish', 'conditional_email', 10, 0);

function conditional_email() {
  wp_mail('my@email.com','test','test');
}

?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try with simple PHP mail() function? or use SMTP.

Comment: Unfortunately that also appears to do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add parameters `$old_status` and `$new_status` to the function.

```
  function conditional_email( $old_status, $new_status) {
   wp_mail('my@email.com','test','test');
  }
```

You will see that in the example [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions)

Hope it works after !

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the post transition hook as opposed to the new to publish hook, and with your additions it works perfectly now.

Comment: Great, you can see a plugin I've done to follow new post and correction made by author : Brozzme multiple admin emails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you passed zero parameters, but the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions#.7Bold_status.7D_to_.7Bnew_status.7D_Hook) clearly specifies that:

> It is necessary to specify the number of arguments `do_action()` should pass to the callback function.

Also another nice thing to know: this hook does not run if you click on `new post`, type in the title and immediately hit the `publish` button. It only runs if you wait for WordPress to generate the URL for the post! It is because of a `DOING_AUTOSAVE` condition in the core function.

So here is the corrected code for you:

```php
add_action( 'new_to_publish', 'conditional_email', 10, 1);

/**
 * Send emails based on categories when a post is published
 *
 * @param \WP_Post $post
 */
function conditional_email( $post ) {
  wp_mail( 'my@email.com', 'test', 'test' );
}
```